# How do I create Surfaces in a Container Surface using Famo.us

Tags: javascript, html, css, famo.us

I want to have  inside  
like

```
<div main>
    <div content>
        my content
    </div>
</div>
```

And what about surfaces inside surfaces? 
I can't do:

```
new Surface({
    content: new Surface({})
});
```

I want it to be laid out like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcqHn.png

[EDIT]My question is how to create the layout in the picture using famo.us. Specifically, how to have a div inside a div or surface inside a surface. I'm looking at the famo.us layout example now, thanks

Comment: What are you asking here?

Comment: Check out http://famo.us/university/home/#/layouts they have some examples there.

Comment: Use a ContainerSurface in the famous/surfaces/ContainerSurface.js package. It allows you to create this sort of nested structure as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the GridLayout for the items and add the grid to a ContainerSurface.  Of course, there are other ways to accomplish your layout. You should lay it out based on the use case needed.

**[Example on jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ropola/2/edit?js,output)**

```js
  var mainContext = Engine.createContext();

  var container = new ContainerSurface({
    size: [400, 400],
    properties: {
      overflow: 'hidden',
      backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (100 * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)"
    }
  });
  var grid = new GridLayout({
    dimensions: [2, 2],
    gutterSize: [30, 30]
  });

  var surfaces = [];
  grid.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

  var temp;
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    temp = new Surface({
      size: [150, 150],
      content: 'I am surface: ' + (i + 1),
      properties: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        lineHeight: '150px',
        backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 40) + ", 100%, 50%)"
      }
    });

    surfaces.push(temp);
  }

  container.add(grid);

  mainContext.add(new Modifier({
    align: [0.5, 0.5],
    origin: [0.5, 0.5]
  })).add(container);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a SurfaceContainer

```
var container = new ContainerSurface({
   classes:[ "some-class"]
});

var surf1 = new Surface({content: "Hello World"});
var surf2 = new Surface({content: "Second Surface"});
container.add(surf1);
container.add(surf2);
```